# SML: How to check if exceptions have been raised?

Tags: io, sml

I am writing some simple programs about reading and writing files in SML, and I am thinking to track if a file is **successfully opened / overflow happens**, etc. If any exceptions are raised during complilation, I want the function to return false else true.

Is such implementation doable? If so, how? If not, any alternative solutions?

---

I am not sure if I am doing it correctly:

```
fun getN(file) = 
let 
    val input = TextIO.openIn file
    fun num(n) = 
        case n of
             NONE => []
           | SOME(str) => str_to_num(str) @ num(TextIO.inputLine input)
in 
    if OS.FileSys.access(file, []) then 
        num(TextIO.inputLine input) before TextIO.closeIn input
    else []
//OR
    num(TextIO.inputLine input) before TextIO.closeIn input
    handle Io => []
end;
```

However, neither of these solutions does not return [] when the directory of the file does not exist. Why?

Comment: "If any exceptions are raised during complilation" Do you mean during runtime? Look into the `handle` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is doable:

```
fun wasExceptionRaised f x = (f x; false) handle e => true
```

This will execute `f x`, discard the result and return `false`, unless an exception was raised, in which case that exception, `e`, is handled, discarded and `true` is returned. Although you probably want to handle specific exceptions and not others, for example when testing:

```
val test_should_not_find_file =
    (TextIO.openIn "non-existing-file"; false)
    handle Io { cause = SysErr ("No such file or directory", _), ... } => true
         | _ => false
```

If you're just logging if an exception was thrown, you may do something similar:

```
structure YourLogger =
struct
    fun logException e =
        let val time = Date.toString (Date.fromTimeLocal (Time.now ()))
            val msg = "On " ^ time ^ " an error occurred: "
                    ^ General.exnName e ^ ".\n"
                    ^ General.exnMessage e
        in appendFile "myLog.txt" msg end

    fun logged f x = f x handle e => (logException e; raise e)
end
```

Now, instead of calling `f x`, you may call `logged f x` to get the same result, but where any exceptions are logged.